# Executing command through a c program on Windows

Tags: c, windows, command-prompt, execution

I want to know how to execute a command from a c program,on windows os.
To be more specific how to write a c program whose output will not be printed but directly goes to command prompt and get executed there? please help me

Comment: Confused. Are you saying there are C commands you want to run on the command prompt?

Comment: Are you sure you don't want a batch file?

Comment: i want to send the output of a c program to command prompt

Comment: And execute it immediately or to run later?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to use system() command in your C code.
For example:

```
system("pause");
```

where "pause" is the command to be executed in cmd.

reference: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/system/

I hope i got your question right.

Comment: @julius skrisa i have a small doubt,if the command i want to use is something like this 'pause"pause"pause' what i have to do? pls help me with this

Comment: If you mean to use qoutes in command string.. you need to escape them. Check this: [answer](http://superuser.com/questions/713074/how-do-i-escape-spaces-in-command-line-in-windows)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand the question correctly. But if I do, you're looking for the [system()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/system/) function.

Comment: yes that's what i was looking for but the comman i want to use has " in it so,what to do?

Comment: @user3434140 Use `\"`. Like `system("cd \"New Folder\"");` See this [wikipedia aritcle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequences_in_C).

Answer (score 0):

I suspect what you are describing is the the back-ticks in shells in Linux/Unix.

However, I don't know how to do that in Windows.

**Unix way**

```
myprompt>  `./a.out`
```

If the C program was basically:  `printf("ls -l .\n");`, then this should list the files.
Is that what you wanted?

Like I said, I don't know how to do that in the Win Cmd Prompt, but maybe this clarifies your question.

---

Looks like you could try:

```
C:\MyDir> MyProgram.exe | cmd.exe /C
```